# Else if, or statement in Xcode. Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Tags: iphone, xcode, logic, if-statement

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but Xcode keeps saying "Expected expression".  What is wrong with the else if, or statement below?

```
else if ([currentClass rangeOfString:@"English"].location != NSNotFound) || ([currentClass rangeOfString:@"Literature"].location != NSNotFound) {
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"englishicon.png"];

}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing an extra set of parentheses for the entire `if()`.

Answer (score 7):

You have to wrap your if statement between parentheses.

```
if (([currentClass rangeOfString:@"English"].location != NSNotFound) || ([currentClass rangeOfString:@"Literature"].location != NSNotFound)) {
```